# php - db2 connection in centos6.2

Tags: php, db2

I have db2 database in 192.168.0.xxx:xx and my application (PHP script) in 192.168.0.xxx (Cent OS 6.2).
So I need to execute some db2 queries through the php script.

- **PHP** 5.3.3
- **CentOS** release 6.2 (Final)
- **LSB Version** :core-4.0-ia32:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-ia32:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-ia32:printing-4.0-noarch
- **DATABASE** IBM DB2 10.1 X64

I believe that I need to create a connection to DB2 server. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
You will have to install libstdc++ dependency before getting db2 to work. Do

```
yum install libstdc++.so.6
```

Also don't forget to set permissions for the installation dir

```
chmod 777 /<installation dir>
```

To create a new connection to an IBM DB2

```
resource db2_connect ( string $database , string $username , string $password [, array $options ] )
```

An example:-

```
<?php
$conn = db2_connect($database, $user, $password);

// Create the test table
$create = 'CREATE TABLE animals (id INTEGER, breed VARCHAR(32),
    name CHAR(16), weight DECIMAL(7,2))';
$result = db2_exec($conn, $create);
if ($result) {
    print "Successfully created the table.\n";
}

// Populate the test table
$animals = array(
    array(0, 'cat', 'Pook', 3.2),
    array(1, 'dog', 'Peaches', 12.3),
    array(2, 'horse', 'Smarty', 350.0),
    array(3, 'gold fish', 'Bubbles', 0.1),
    array(4, 'budgerigar', 'Gizmo', 0.2),
    array(5, 'goat', 'Rickety Ride', 9.7),
    array(6, 'llama', 'Sweater', 150)
);

foreach ($animals as $animal) {
    $rc = db2_exec($conn, "INSERT INTO animals (id, breed, name, weight)
      VALUES ({$animal[0]}, '{$animal[1]}', '{$animal[2]}', {$animal[3]})");
    if ($rc) {
        print "Insert... ";
    }
}
?>
```

This script will output

```
Successfully created the table.
Insert... Insert... Insert... Insert... Insert... Insert... Insert...
```

See the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ibm-db2.php)

Comment: Hi Tony, Thank you for quick reply but I have the script and works fine via Xampp (windows platform). Now I need to implement the same in CentOS  6.2 and would like to know whether any additional configuration i may need to do it in centos